# regular expression to get contents after match till end of line

Tags: regex, vbscript

Example: if it's like

```
some text Match: here is the content I want<br>
Match: here is the content I want
```

I am trying to get whatever information after `Match:` till end the end of line.

Regular expression which I  am using now is `?=Match:(. *)?=\n`

Issue1: Match: is not getting eliminated.
Issue2: there are some html tags which randomly occur. So I have to eliminate them if they occur.

So in any case I just need "here is the content I want".

Can someone tell me modification that I need to do for my regular expression?

Comment: Please reformat your question and make sure you share the exact pattern you are using, and describe the issue with the regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Changes done and i have mentioned the issue which i am facing as well

Comment: I strongly doubt you provided the exact regex. It is [invalid](https://regex101.com/r/mO9pK6/1).

Comment: In case you havent found any help online regarding formatting posts - [see this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: It is not only formatting, we can access the question source and see the raw text. The thing is that the pattern is not a real regex pattern that can be used in VBScript. The question is unclear without that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can approach this:

1. Remove everything before/after the submatch:

   ```
   s = "..."

   Set re = New RegExp
   re.Pattern = "^[\s\S]*?Match: (.*)[\s\S]*"

   WScript.Echo re.Replace(s, "$1")
   ```

   `^[\s\S]*?` matches any character (including newlines) up to the first occurrence of the term "Match:". `(.*)` then matches all characters up to the next newline. Your expression must cover everything before and after the submatch, because the replacement won't touch unmatched parts of the string.
2. Extract the submatch:

   ```
   s = "..."

   Set re = New RegExp
   re.Pattern = "Match: (.*)"

   For Each m In re.Execute(s)
     WScript.Echo m.Submatches(0)
   Next
   ```

   With this approach the regular expression is simpler, because it only needs to cover what you actually want to match (instead of having to cover the parts you want to remove as well). On the other hand, the handling of the submatch takes a little more work.